# How to change e-mail category in MS Outlook 2013 with VBA?

Tags: vba, outlook

I try to make macro that automatically change email category after finishing some actions in VBA.

I create some code that looks good, but there is problem with it that is not always working - sometimes category don't change and it look like that are errors with it:

```
Dim myolApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
Set ns = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myolApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set olFolder = myolApp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
Dim itm As Object
Dim mailcattable As Variant
Dim kategoria As String

For Each itm In olFolder.Items

For b = 0 To UBound(mailcattable)
    If mailcattable(b) = "ABCD" Then
       mailcattable(b) = "After ABCD"
       kategoria = Join(mailcattable, "; ")
       itm.Categories = kategoria
    End If
Next
Next
```

Can you tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never save the item. It is also a good idea to reset the `kategoria` variable for each item.

```
    Dim bModified As Boolean
    For Each itm In olFolder.Items
      kategoria = ""
      bModified = false
      For b = 0 To UBound(mailcattable)
        If mailcattable(b) = "ABCD" Then
           mailcattable(b) = "After ABCD"
           kategoria = Join(mailcattable, "; ")
           itm.Categories = kategoria
           bModified = true
        End If
      Next
      if bModified Then 
        itm.Save
      End If 
    Next
```

Comment: Thank you! Reseting "kategoria" variable really helps!